# Disobeying parents

Tags: parents, halal-haram

Asalamualaikum,
I am asking for my cousin
 I wanted to know if disobeying your parents is haram under this circumstance. 
I have got A levels within a few months and I need to study. However my mother asks me to do things which take a lot of my time up like travellijgnto send food or clothes etc. Is it haram to say no if I need to study?
 Kind regards 
Abdul

Answer (score 1):

[An-Nasaa’i (2562)](https://sunnah.com/urn/1077390) narrated that

> Ibn ‘Umar said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “There are three whom Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will not look at on the Day of Resurrection: the one who disobeys his parents, the woman who acts in a masculine manner, and the cuckold. And there are three who will not enter Paradise: the one who disobeys his parents, the one who is addicted to alcohol, and the one who reminds people of what he has given to them.”

It is best to listen to your parents and do what they say. If you are really eager to study simply have a calm and nice conversation with them explaining what you have to do and that you may be able to help later on. If this does not go as planned then try to fit study times and times for chores.